# Excel - Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In excel I have two sheets.

If a certain cell is not null in sheet two
then in sheet 1 I want a certain cell (that has string value in it already) to have it's background highlight in blue.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/09/03/conditional-formatting-from-different-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>Is this possible?</sub>

Yes, this is possible but cross referencing worksheets may only be possible in xl2010 and later versions. There are ways to get around this limitation with named ranges for previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Name your certain cell in sheet two, select the certain cell in sheet 1 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=LEN(a_certain_cell)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select blue colour Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.